# How to get URL of single page web app in Android WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to convert an existing single page webapp to Android application using JAVA. But I dont want to display home page of that webapp, instead I want to display a scrolling layout when user select homepage of the webapp. In chrome web-browser I get url address like https:example.com/homepage, https://example.com/profile, https:example.com/orders etc. Using following code I can only get the url when the webapp loads initially. Please help me.

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains("pinterest_board_photo")){
            Log.d("ON PAGE STARTED ","CONTAINS HOMEPAGE");
        }
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        webview.setVisibility(webview.INVISIBLE);
       // scrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       // scrollView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.setVisibility(webview.VISIBLE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

I tried onLoadResource , onPageStarted, OnPageFinished etc methods but not able to get the url after loading of the page. I want to show my custom layout when user goes on "Homepage".

Answer (score 0):

Apply WebviewClient and use below method to get url

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
 return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request.getUrl().toString());
}
```

e.g. like

```
browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.shoppingBrowser);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Log.v(item, item);
getUserPreference();
browser.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
browser.loadUrl(url);

 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String notuse) {
    Log.v("shopping", url+" loaded");



   return true;
}
```